# Stop child goroutine when parent returns

Tags: go, goroutine

We have a main go routine who spawns a parent goroutine, which inturn spawns a child go routine.

The child goroutine still runs even after parent returns. This leads to goroutine leak.

How do we avoid this?

Below I have added a code snippet to simulate the following
Here child goroutine can be anything which is a long running process, like db query, api call, etc

```
Program output: 

In main function -  1
Starting parent function -  2
Starting child function -  3
Child timed out -  3
Completed parent -  2  // Implying that child goroutine is still running with main routine
```

```py
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

// WaitGroup used by main to wait for parent goroutine
var wg sync.WaitGroup

// Long duration process time
var duration = 100


func main() {
    fmt.Println("In main function - ", runtime.NumGoroutine())
    wg.Add(1)
    go parentRoutine()
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Completed parent - ", runtime.NumGoroutine())
}

func parentRoutine() {
    fmt.Println("Starting parent function - ", runtime.NumGoroutine())
    childRes := make(chan int)


        // Spawning child goroutine
    go func() {

               // Here the child is a simulation of a long running process which might take more time than expected timeout. It runs even after parent returns due to timeout


        fmt.Println("Starting child function - ", runtime.NumGoroutine())
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(duration)*time.Second)
        fmt.Println("Child ended - ", runtime.NumGoroutine())
        childRes <- 1
    }()

    select {
    case <-childRes:
        fmt.Println("Child completed - ", runtime.NumGoroutine())
    case <- time.After(time.Duration(3)*time.Second):
        fmt.Println("Child timed out - ", runtime.NumGoroutine())
    }
    wg.Done()
}
```

Comment: Goroutines are don't normally have a "parent", and there's no requirement to have one to prevent a leak. You simply need to ensure that your goroutines aren't blocked from exiting. The normal method for timeouts and cancellation is to use a `Context`

Comment: How can contexts be used to solve this? Can you please share a code snippet

Comment: There are examples in the documentation: [`WithCancel`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#example_WithCancel), [`WithTimeout`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#example_WithTimeout), and a post here as well [Go Concurrency Patterns: Context](https://blog.golang.org/context). What specific question do you have?

Comment: The `context` pkg is heavily used in the go standard library uses for any network/blocking calls. So you should use it too. They chain nicely with cascading effects - thus avoiding lower-level code being aware of how a higher-level task is implemented.

Comment: Can anyone please modify the above code snippet to how context can solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Here is your snippet with context: https://play.golang.org/p/0TXyt4vuGKJ.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

// WaitGroup used by main to wait for parent goroutine
var wg sync.WaitGroup

// Long duration process time
var duration = 100

func main() {
    fmt.Println("In main function - ", runtime.NumGoroutine())
    wg.Add(1)
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    go parentRoutine(ctx)
    wg.Wait()
    cancel()
    time.Sleep(time.Second) //If main immediately exists the child goroutine does not
                            //have the time to terminate.
    fmt.Println("Completed parent - ", runtime.NumGoroutine())
}

func parentRoutine(ctx context.Context) {
    fmt.Println("Starting parent function - ", runtime.NumGoroutine())
    childRes := make(chan int)

    // Spawning child goroutine
    go func(ctx context.Context) {

        // Here the child is a simulation of a long running process which might take more time than expected timeout. It runs even after parent returns due to timeout

        fmt.Println("Starting child function - ", runtime.NumGoroutine())
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("Child's context expired - ", runtime.NumGoroutine())
        case <-time.After(time.Duration(duration) * time.Second):
            //time consuming task
        }
        fmt.Println("Child ended - ", runtime.NumGoroutine())
        childRes <- 1
    }(ctx)

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("Parent's context expired - ", runtime.NumGoroutine())
    case <-childRes:
        fmt.Println("Child completed - ", runtime.NumGoroutine())
    case <-time.After(time.Duration(3) * time.Second):
        fmt.Println("Child timed out - ", runtime.NumGoroutine())
    }
    wg.Done()
}
```

The output is the following now:

```
In main function -  1
Starting parent function -  2
Starting child function -  3
Child timed out -  3
Child's context expired -  2
Child ended -  2
Completed parent -  2
```